# How can I update my displayed ETA and Distance values? Swift 4 MKDirections MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, geolocation, mapkit

In my viewDidLoad I retrieve the current location and the location of the store chosen (which location is stored on Firebase Database via Geofire)
I have displayed the calculated ETA and Distance in the viewDidLoad however it's not updating when I go outside and go along the route. How can I update the directionsLbl and etaLbl whenever the user moves? Any suggestions? I've posted my viewDidLoad and didUpdateLocations functions. Thanks in advance.

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
    let userLat = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
    let userLon = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
    myLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: userLat!, longitude: userLon!)
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    // Create request
    self.request.destination = self.destinationMapItem
    self.request.source = self.self.sourceMapItem!
    self.request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.walking
    self.request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
    let directions = MKDirections(request: self.request)
    directions.calculate { response, error in
        if let route = response?.routes.first {
            let time = self.secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: route.expectedTravelTime)
            print("Distance: \(route.distance), ETA: \(time)")
            self.etaLbl.text = "\(time)mins"
            let miles = route.distance / 1609.344
            self.distanceLbl.text = "\(String(describing: numberFormatter.string(from: miles as NSNumber)!))m"
            for step in route.steps {
                self.directionslbl.text = step.instructions
            }
            self.mapView.camera.altitude = 500

            self.mapView.add(route.polyline)
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView.showsBuildings = false
    self.mapView.isRotateEnabled = false
    self.mapView.showsCompass = false
    self.mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = false
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
    geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: ref.child("Store Locations"))
    print(store!)
    self.orderIDLbl.text = orderID!
    self.storeLbl.text = store!
    geoFire?.getLocationForKey(store!, withCallback: { (location, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print("ERROR IS: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

        } else {

            self.destinationStore = location
            print("LOCATION OF STORE IS: \(String(describing: self.destinationStore!))")
            // Get destination position
            let storeLong = self.destinationStore?.coordinate.longitude
            let storeLat = self.destinationStore?.coordinate.latitude
            let storeLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: storeLat!, longitude: storeLong!)
            let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: storeLocation.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
            let anno = StoreAnnotation(coordinate: storeLocation.coordinate, storeName: self.store!)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(anno)
            self.destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
            self.request.destination = self.destinationMapItem
            self.request.source = self.self.sourceMapItem!
            self.request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.walking
            self.request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
            let directions = MKDirections(request: self.request)
            directions.calculate { response, error in
                if let route = response?.routes.first {
                    let time = self.secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: route.expectedTravelTime)
                    print("Distance: \(route.distance), ETA: \(time)")
                    self.etaLbl.text = "\(time)mins"
                    let miles = route.distance / 1609.344
                    self.distanceLbl.text = "\(String(describing: numberFormatter.string(from: miles as NSNumber)!))m"
                    self.directionsArray = route.steps
                    print(route.steps)
                    for step in route.steps {
                        self.directionslbl.text = step.instructions
                    }
                    //self.mapView.camera.heading = self.directionsArray[0].
                    self.mapView.add(route.polyline)
                } else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }

    })

    let userLat = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
    let userLon = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
    myLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: userLat!, longitude: userLon!)
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
    mapView.camera.altitude = 500
    mapView.camera.pitch = 30



    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    // Get current position
    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: (myLocation?.coordinate)!, addressDictionary: nil)
    self.sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)

    let orderStatusRef = ref.child("Users").child(currentUserID!).child("Current Order").child(orderID!)

    orderStatusRef.observe(.value) { (DataSnapshot) in

        let dict = DataSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let orderStatus = dict!["Order Status"] as? Int

        switch orderStatus! {

        case 0:
            self.orderStatusLbl.text = "Received"
            self.orderStatusLbl.textColor = UIColor.red
        case 1:
            self.orderStatusLbl.text = "Being Prepared"
            self.orderStatusLbl.textColor = UIColor.orange


        default:
            break
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't run your code, but you call StopUpdatingLocations within the DidUpdateLocations, so I dont think you will get more than one Location Update ?

Comment: Also above that your setting of the current location should come from the "locations" parameter (set loc = locations.last!)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and wasn't able to find any solutions available online. There are likely better ways of going about this, but I'll provide you with what worked for me.

*This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so I apologize in advance for any clarity and/or formatting issues.*

---

I defined two variables at the top of my class. Two of them are for the timers we are about to create. The other two are used for updating ETA as you progress through your route.

```
var directionsTimer: Timer? // For updating the turn-by-turn directions
var etaTimer: Timer? // For updating the ETA label


var calculatingETA = false // To make sure we aren't running two ETA calculations at the same time
```

---

Then I set both of those timers up by running this function after the directions have been calculated.

```
 private func setupTimers() {
    self.etaTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 20.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in self.updateETA() })
    self.directionsTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in self.updateDirectionLabels() }
}
```

---

The 'etaTimer' is set to run the below function every twenty seconds. This function will keep the ETA label within your UI up-to-date, while progressing along the route.

```
private func updateETA() {
        
        // Grab the device's current location (in coordinates)
        guard let currentLocationCoordinate = self.currentCoordinate else { print("Unable To Validate Current Location."); return }
        
        // Create a MKMapItem from the device's current location
        let currentLocationItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: currentLocationCoordinate))
        
        // Grab the location of your route's destination (preferably as a MKMapItem)
        guard let destinationItem = self.destinations?.first else { print("Unable To Validate Destination."); return }
        
        // Create a MKMapItem from the route's destination
        // !! My destination was already saved as an MKMapItem, if yours is not, you can just repeat the same above step !! //
        
        // Make sure the last calculation is finished
        if self.calculatingETA == false {
            
            // Here we will create a new MKDirections item, starting from the device's current location, going to your route's destination
            
            let req = MKDirections.Request()
                req.source = currentLocationItem // Place your current location item here
                req.destination = destinationItem // Place your destination item here
                req.transportType = .automobile
            
            let directions = MKDirections(request: req)
            
            // Set this variable to true
            self.calculatingETA = true
            
            directions.calculateETA { (response, error) in
                if let res = response {
                    
                    // You now have an up-to-date ETA
                    let etaString = res.expectedTravelTime.toETAString()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.etaLabel.text = etaString }
                    
                    // Set this variable to false. We have finished calculating
                    self.calculatingETA = false
                    
                    Print("Updated ETA: \(etaString)", .info)
                }
                else if let err = error {
                    self.calculatingETA = false
                    
                    Print("Unable To Update ETA. [MESSAGE] \(err.localizedDescription)", .error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

The 'directionsTimer' is set to run the below function every five seconds. This function will update the 'distance until next turn' label within your UI.

```
private func updateDirectionLabels() {

    // Make sure the current step is within bounds
    if (self.steps.isEmpty == false) && (self.stepCounter < self.steps.count) {

        // Define the current step
        let currentStep = self.steps[self.stepCounter]
        
        // Update the instructions to match the current MKRoute.Step
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.directionLabel.text = currentStep.instructions }
        
        // Grab the device's current location (in coordinates)
        if let currentCoordinate = self.currentCoordinate {

            // Create a CLLocation object from the device's coordinates
            let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: currentCoordinate.latitude, longitude: currentCoordinate.longitude)
            
            // Grab the coordinates for the current MKRoute.Step
            let currentStepCoordinate = currentStep.polyline.coordinate

            // Create a CLLocation object from the step's coordinates
            let currentStepLocation = CLLocation(latitude: currentStepCoordinate.latitude, longitude: currentStepCoordinate.longitude)
            
            // Get the distance between the device's current location and the location of the next step
            let distanceToStep = currentLocation.distance(from: currentStepLocation)

            // Format the result
            let distanceInMiles = Double(distanceToStep * 0.00062).rounded()
            
            // Update label displaying the distance until next turn
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.directionDistanceLabel.text = String(describing: distanceInMiles) }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I might have gone a little overboard with the comments, but I hope this helps.